Relative Hazard rate
I was wondering how I might get the relative hazard rate for the example below (Cox regression).*
library("survival")
library("survminer")
res.cox <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
res.cox


The point of the Cox model is that there is no need to estimate the hazard rate. While it is a feature of the disease generating process, the Cox model cleverly deals with ratios of events over time so that you can estimate a hazard ratio. The hazard ratio is what tells you whether sex is associated with lung cancer.

The way the question is stated I’m guessing that you have not studied the field of survival analysis nor the Cox proportional hazards model.  Studying a field is important, before attempting to do analyses.  Also, survminer has nothing to do with this problem.

As you start to learn about survival analysis, I'd recommend that you don't use survminer. It isn't as well vetted as the main survival package, it had at least one long-neglected major coding error, and default settings that can sometimes obscure important parts of the data and results.

You have to distinguish between the hazard rate, which isn't modeled directly in Cox proportional hazards (PH) regression, from a hazard ratio, which is.
The hazard rate is the instantaneous risk of having an event, given that you are still at risk.
A hazard ratio is a ratio of hazard rates between two scenarios, for example male versus female or infected versus non-infected. Under the PH assumption, hazard ratios are taken to be independent of time or the underlying hazard rates.
A Cox PH regression works in the log-hazard scale, with regression coefficients that are the log-hazard differences between scenarios (or for a 1-unit change in a continuous predictor). You exponentiate the regression coefficient to get the hazard ratio, reported as exp(coef) in the survival package that you used. As another answer notes, the summary() of a model can provide more information.

I removed my answer, @EdM's answer is more complete (+1)!!

@EdM, thanks so much for your time.
